# Can't import war file into eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, web

I've worked on a project and exported it as a war file on a school computer, I came home and I can't manage to find the war file import option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To use the *Import Existing Project* option of eclipse, the directory to import must contain the *.project* file of eclipse. If this file doesn't exist, you can't import as *exisiting project*. I am not sure if the directory *.settings* is required also, but I assume it is not.

**Only** in the case your war file contains the java sources (*.java) extract the file like so:

```
jar xf youWarFile.war
```

and afterwards you can use the **file system** import option of eclipse.

But you have to reconfigure you eclipse project, because the war file surely won't contain the required .project file and the .settings directory.